# NSwagStudio to use subpaths

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate Swagger from .net code.
I have the following function:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetItemSubItem(int id, string subItem)
```

This is called by using /api/items/{id}/{subItem}, but NSwagStudio only generates it as /api/items/{id} with subItem appearing as in:query.

Is there a way to make NSwagStudio know this should be part of the path?

Comment: can you show a bit more code? maybe the entire controller for `GetItemSubItem`

Comment: also it will be nice to see your swagger.json file...